flutter_downloader issues on downloading pdf files
Anyone implemented file download using flutter_downloader package. I have some issues with it.
The file is getting downloaded to my apps directory for the first time .but in the notification bar it shows failed also in the console too it shows failed. Does anyone else successfully implemented this?
I will attach my code and other info below
here's the packages i use
flutter_downloader: ^1.11.6
permission_handler: ^11.0.1
path_provider: ^2.1.2

below is the complete code
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callback(String id, int status, int progress) {
  log('cal ack----------id=$id--stauus=$status---progress=$progress');
  if (status == DownloadTaskStatus.complete.index) {
    final SendPort? send =
        IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
    send?.send([id, status, progress]);
  }
  else{
    log('this is $status');
  }
}

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(debug: true,ignoreSsl: true);
  await FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(callback);

  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  final ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        _port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');

    _port.listen((message) {

      log(message);
      String id = message[0];

      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        FlutterDownloader.loadTasksWithRawQuery(
                query: "SELECT * FROM task WHERE task_id='$id'")
            .then((tasks) {
          if (tasks == null || tasks.isEmpty) return;

          final task = tasks.first;
          final taskId = task.taskId;
          final filename = task.filename;
          final path = task.savedDir;

          // TODO: check here the file path and filename of the task
          // these aren't the correct ones, when saveInPublicStorage is true
          // furthermore the file is renamed, when existing to 'filename.pdf (1)', filename.pdf (2), and so on
          // perhaps a renaming before the file extension would be better: 'filename (1).pdf' instead of 'filename.pdf (1)'
          log('Task: $taskId, status: $path, progress: $filename');

          FlutterDownloader.open(taskId: id)
              .then((value) => {debugPrint('Open file: $value')});
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future _tryDeleteExistingFile(String? path, String filename) async {
    try {
      File file = File('$path/$filename');
      if (await file.exists()) {
        await file.delete();
      }
    } catch (err, stack) {
      debugPrint("Cannot delete existing file");
    }
  }

  _downloadFile() async {

    
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
                  if (!status.isGranted) {
                    await Permission.storage.request();
                  }
    debugPrint('Download file');
    const urlString =
        'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf';


        try {
          final path = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;

    log('path==$path');

    // this one is needed for duplicate downloads into the externalStorageDirectory
    // await _tryDeleteExistingFile(path, 'dummy.pdf');

    final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
      url: urlString,
      savedDir:
          path, // here we could also use the 'await getDownloadsDirectory().path' instead
      headers: {},
      showNotification: true,
      openFileFromNotification: true,
      // saveInPublicStorage: true,

    );
        } catch (e) {
          log(e.toString());
        }
    


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
        color: Colors.blue,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Download File Example'),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Center(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  onPressed: _downloadFile,
                  child: const Text('Download File'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

I am also attaching the screen shot of the notification bar in my phone and my console for more clarity
Console Screenshot
notification bar screen shot
this is my manifest file.
I done according to package documentation. I am able to download the file but in console t says failed and also in the notification bar it is showing failed.

Care to send the screenshot of the downloaded file in the said app directory?
